# How to change slot's style

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using vue-select in the project and I ran into the problem cause I cannot understand how to change dynamically style of slot.

This is what I found in their documentation:

```
<slot v-for="option in valueAsArray" name="selected-option-container"
        :option="(typeof option === 'object')?option:{[label]: option}" :deselect="deselect" :multiple="multiple" :disabled="disabled">
<span class="selected-tag" v-bind:key="option.index">
    <slot name="selected-option" v-bind="(typeof option === 'object')?option:{[label]: option}">
        {{ getOptionLabel(option) }}
    </slot>
    <button v-if="multiple" :disabled="disabled" @click="deselect(option)" type="button" class="close" aria-label="Remove option">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
</span>
```

And now I need to change the color style of `selected-tag` depends on the option passed. How to change it through the template slot?